# How to do group by based on the folder names when row contains path as string?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I am relatively new to SQL and BigQuery both. I have a table where one of the rows looks like `home/desktop/parent/child/grandchild`. I want to have the flexibility to choose the 'group by' condition so sometime it could be group by the root which is 'home' here and sometimes by any other folder name in the hierarchy. Is there any generic way to achieve this ? I have thought a lot about it but all I can think about is parsing the row values as Strings and do some substring operations here but I am not clear about how to make a generic query for the same. Appreciate any corrections to the question, I know it's kinda vague but I have tried my best to put it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

To implement your idea on parsing row values and apply string manipulation. See 2 approaches that I have thought of using a simple sample data.

Approach 1:

Use [regexp_extract](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) to capture the path that you want to use for `group by`. If you want to change the grouping by another folder name, you can add another `regex_extract` to extract that specific folder name and use it in `group by`.

```
with data as (
    select 'home/desktop/parent/child/grandchild' as path, 'John' as owner,
    union all select 'home/desktop/parent/child/grandchild_1' as path, 'Mark' as owner,
    union all select 'home/desktop/parent/child/grandchild_2' as path, 'Ron' as owner,
    union all select 'root/desktop/parent/child/grandchild_3' as path, 'Jason' as owner,
    union all select 'root/desktop/parent/child/grandchild_4' as path, 'Pat' as owner,
),

get_root_path as (
select 
    regexp_extract(path, r'^(\w+)\/\w+') as root_path,
    path,
    owner
from data
)

select 
    count(root_path) as count_root_path, 
    root_path from get_root_path
group by root_path
```

Output (Approach 1):

[image]

Approach 2:

Use [regexp_extract_all](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) to capture everything based on the defined regex. The values then can be accessed using indices. Adjust the increment value in `[OFFSET(0)]` (Ex. `[OFFSET(1)]` will return `desktop` and so on) to get the next folder. Just make sure that your regex is correct.

```
with data as (
    select 'home/desktop/parent/child/grandchild' as path, 'John' as owner,
    union all select 'home/desktop/parent/child/grandchild_1' as path, 'Mark' as owner,
    union all select 'home/desktop/parent/child/grandchild_2' as path, 'Ron' as owner,
    union all select 'root/desktop/parent/child/grandchild_3' as path, 'Jason' as owner,
    union all select 'root/desktop/parent/child/grandchild_4' as path, 'Pat' as owner,
),

get_folder_names as (
select 
    regexp_extract_all(path, r'(\w+)\/?') as folder_name,
    path,
    owner
from data
)

select 
    count(folder_name[OFFSET(0)]) as count_folder,
    folder_name[OFFSET(0)] as folder

from get_folder_names
group by folder_name[OFFSET(0)]
```

Output(Approach 2):

[image]